# How can i fix "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'emit')"

Tags: websocket, nestjs

I need to send a post request from front-end with text. Than this post-request will send message back using WebSocket by emitting. Every time I post request there is this error "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'emit')".
[40th line is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1okV.png)
repo: https://github.com/Dimmetrodon/chat-app-backend-websocket

Tried removing the line to see if it is even getting this request. It is.
Tried adding afterInit, didn't fix the problem.